# how do I run js in atom? I get a bash error when saving the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, atom-editor

I'm learning javascript and trying to run my code in atom. I've installed node.js but when I save the file I get:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
[Finished in 0.137s]
```

I saved the file as learning.js on my desktop. Sorry if this is very vague

Comment: "Sorry if this is very vague" it's fine, happens when you're new. Please explain how you are trying to run your Javascript code (how/why is *bash* being invoked), please post the code you are trying to run (maybe missing a backtick to close a template literal?). Do you get the error trying to *run* your code or *save the file*?

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm using node.js so I don't have to run it in a browser but in atom. The code I wrote was just a simple `console.log("Hello world");`. Basically my goal is to run js code in a console not on a browser. I'm running Mac OS X if that helps.

Comment: The code works but doesn't when its saved

Comment: How are you running the code? Because it sounds like you are trying to run it with bash instead of node.

Comment: with a package called "script" in atom (https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script) thanks for your help

Comment: also I get the error when I save and run the file. if I didn't save it, it works fine but if I did I get the error :/

Comment: Ok. Atom doesn't (AFAIK) have an integrated shell. Open up terminal (hit cmd-space for quick launch and type 'terminal' and it should show up). Navigate to wherever you saved the file in the shell. Type without quotes `node learning.js` and it should work. If it says that it doesn't recognize node as a command, install it with homebrew. If you don't have homebrew yet, install that first. You can easily google how to do those. Sorry if this is all complicated, but you'll have to learn it anyway and as you've discovered trying to shortcut it means that you have no idea when something fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node <filename.js>`

You need to invoke node like `node learning.js` instead of however you're doing it that's calling bash.

Comment: That's a guess, not an answer.

Comment: Yeah the question is too vague and and  i think he/she is probably trying to run it as shell script unconsciously.

Comment: Recommend deleting this and posting it as a comment on the question. If your guess proves correct per the OP, you can always undelete it and have them accept it.

Comment: i cant. i don't have much reputation. NewBie Here. Okay i'll delete the answer as you say but it already costed me 2 of my hard earned reputations :(

Comment: I removed the downvote, you should get your rep back. Go ahead and leave it.